# How to get a specific string inside a String delimited by ";"?

Tags: java, java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split strings in J2ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200746/how-do-i-split-strings-in-j2me)

I have a String data which is like csv , that is there are "`;`" inside the String data. But in my case there is always a "`;`" at the end of the String. I want to create a method which gives a String at a certain **`number`** from this csv. For example :

```
String csv = "145557;123456789012;Michael Robert;1000000;200000;;12/05/2011;;" ;
```

In this String there are 8 "`columns`". I say "column" the data between two "`;`" ( the first column is not enclosed by two ";" but only the one at its right ).

In this example the data "`Michael Robert`" has the `number` 2 ( or 3 if we start at 1 for the first column ).

So how to get the data ( column ) at a specified number ?

**NB : I use Java ME**

Comment: Use `StringTokenizer`. Take a look at this duplicate question: [How do I split strings in J2ME?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200746/851811)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In J2ME you can write a method like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csv = "145557;123456789012;Michael Robert;1000000;200000;;12/05/2011;;" ;
        System.out.println(getColumnAt(csv, 0));
        System.out.println(getColumnAt(csv, 1));
        System.out.println(getColumnAt(csv, 2));
    }

    public static String getColumnAt(String csv, int column) {
        int fromIndex = 0;
        int col = 0;
        while (col < column) {
            fromIndex = csv.indexOf(";", fromIndex) + 1;
            col++;
        }
        int toIndex = csv.indexOf(";", fromIndex);
        return csv.substring(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

*UPDATE:* By the way, due to the way that `substring` is implemented it is better to `return new String(csv.substring(fromIndex, toIndex));`, otherwise the substring will hold a reference to the original string and then as long as the substring is not GC-able, the original String won't be GC-able as well.

Comment: I said that I use J2ME , not J2SE !!!!

Answer (score 2):

just use StringTokenizer:

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(yourString,";");
column1 = tok.nextToken();
column2 = tok.nextToken();
...
```

[Here](http://mobilepit.com/09/using-stringtokenizer-in-j2me-javame-applications.html) you can find a more complex example.

Regards,
Luca

Answer (score -2):

```
csv.split(";")[2]; // returns "Michael Robert"
```

This uses the `String.split(String delimiter)` method, which splits the string around the delimiter, returning an array containing the resulting substrings.

Comment: I said that I use J2ME , not J2SE !!!!

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean like this:

```
    public TestClass()
{
    String csv = "145557;123456789012;Michael Robert;1000000;200000;;12/05/2011;;" ;
    System.out.println(splitString(csv,2));
}

public String splitString(String s, int getValueAt)
{
    return s.split(";")[getValueAt];
}
```

Comment: `String.split()` isn't available on J2ME

Comment: I should have read to the end of the question :o