# How to make a char array in J2ME to work as a char in c++

Tags: arrays, file, java-me, text-files

*The title is probably not accurate but I hope that reading this post you can understand what I want to do.*

I'm kind stuck in here. New in Java ME, that unfortunately has, as you know, reduced methods than the Java SE.

What I want to accomplish is this: I have a txt, with numbers in it separated by space.
I want to put them in an array that can ""behave as an usual array in c++"" when one gets numbers separated by space into an array.

Now in J2ME what I've done (using Netbeans) is: I took the txt to a stream. Later sent the stream to a byte array and finally i converted it to a char array.

Let's say the original txt was: 98 2 12 13

Part of the code is:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("models.txt");
try{


   int st_pk1_len = is.available();

   byte st_pk1[] = new byte[st_pk1_len];

   is.read(st_pk1);

   char st_pk1_char[] = new String(st_pk1).toCharArray();

   System.out.println(st_pk1_char);
```

What I get printed is: 98 2 12 13

Although, my problem is that when I want to access index 0 I get only the number 9 and not 98. If I try to reach the number 12, I put the pointer to 3 but what I get is an empty space and so on.

I've searched and tried different methods that I've found without luck to convert that into the original numbers again.

It could be a stupid mistake from my side or something that I've haven't think of.

**Isn't there a simple solution to this problem?**

---

**update** It's working now! Array is working as a "regular"c++ char array. In case somebody else need it or have my same problem, here is how it looks like:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("st_pk1.txt");
int st_pk1_len = is.available(); 
byte st_pk1[] = new byte[st_pk1_len]; 
is.read(st_pk1); 
char st_pk1_char[] = new String(st_pk1).toCharArray(); 
String PreSplitted = new String(st_pk1); 
String AftSplit[] = Split(PreSplitted, " ");
```

If you want to check: `System.out.println(AftSplit[n]);`

For the split method I used the second link in the Gnat's post. 
[Split text in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120014/split-text-in-j2me)

Comment: thanks. I tried but I get "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBytes()
  location: variable st_pk1_char of type char[]". I have the import java.io.* ;

Comment: ooops! sorry I edited instead of make a comment. some one suggested " byte[] ba = st_pk1_char.getBytes();". the post above is my answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the char array as String, containing tokens separated by space: `new String(st_pk1)` does that for you.

After that, you need to split it, like as described in couple other Stack Overflow questions:

- [How do I split strings in J2ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200746/how-do-i-split-strings-in-j2me)
- [Split text in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120014/split-text-in-j2me)

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I'm trying that one. I copied the class of the second link u posted in the same java file. Later I added this part: 
 new String(st_pk1);
          String Splitted  = new Split(st_pk1, " "); but i get "constructor Split in class helloworld.Split cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: byte[],java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length". What I'm missing?

Comment: @user1338101 you're missing that new isn't needed here - it's a method call not object instance creation. Invocation syntax should look like `String splitted = Split(st_pk1, " ")`

Comment: thanks. I changed it to : String PreSplitted = new String(st_pk1);   String AftSplit = Split(PreSplitted, " "); I got this error: incompatible types required: java.lang.String found:    java.lang.String[]... how can I fix it?

Comment: @user1338101 incompatible type indeed, easy to fix: `String[] splitted`. Given you questions I wonder are you familiar with Java language basics? if not consider studying some tutorial for beginners; with this you'll be able to solve such issues faster, not having to wait for instructions at Internet

Comment: i'll consider reading more about the basics. not today at 5 am tho. yeah it's not good to wait for instructions at internet. you forgot the [] in the previous post.

Comment: Ok it's working now! Array is working as a "regular"c++ char array. In case somebody else need it or have my same problem, here is how it looks like:       
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("st_pk1.txt");
int st_pk1_len = is.available();
byte st_pk1[] = new byte[st_pk1_len];
is.read(st_pk1);
char st_pk1_char[] = new String(st_pk1).toCharArray();
String PreSplitted = new String(st_pk1);
String AftSplit[] = Split(PreSplitted, " ");
If you want to check: System.out.println(AftSplit[n]);
for the split method I used the one posted in the second link posted by Gnat.