# Store parts of string in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-me, split

I have a string  `tajmahal.txt sarjan.pdf noorjahan.exe`. I want to store this string in a string array such that `ar[0] = tajmahal.txt`, `ar[1] = sarjan.pdf` and `ar[2] = noorjahan.exe`. How can I do it without using any build functions in java (because I am using j2me which does not support many j2se functions). Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I split strings in J2ME?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200746/how-do-i-split-strings-in-j2me)

Comment: You'd like to create your own custom function? Because you can use the Split function in Java to do so.
Edit: Nevermind, I just saw that this function is not available in J2ME.

Comment: Check with those answers

Answer (score 0):

Since String.split is not available. You can see the implementation of split from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126572/931982)

```
 public static String[] Split(String splitStr, String delimiter) {
     StringBuffer token = new StringBuffer();
     Vector tokens = new Vector();
     // split
     char[] chars = splitStr.toCharArray();
     for (int i=0; i < chars.length; i++) {
         if (delimiter.indexOf(chars[i]) != -1) {
             // we bumbed into a delimiter
             if (token.length() > 0) {
                 tokens.addElement(token.toString());
                 token.setLength(0);
             }
         } else {
             token.append(chars[i]);
         }
     }
     // don't forget the "tail"...
     if (token.length() > 0) {
         tokens.addElement(token.toString());
     }
     // convert the vector into an array
     String[] splitArray = new String[tokens.size()];
     for (int i=0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
         splitArray[i] = (String)tokens.elementAt(i);
     }
     return splitArray;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str="tajmahal.txt sarjan.pdf noorjahan.exe";
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str," ");
    String[] arr=new String[st.countTokens()];
    int i=0;
    while (st.hasMoreElements()){
           arr[i]=st.nextToken();
           i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Java ME configuration/profile set you use.

When it comes to CLDC/MIDP, where there is no collections, StringTokenizer, split(), and so on.

1. count those space(' ')s first.
2. prepare a String[count + 1].
3. split each token while buffering characters with a StringBuffer.

```java
static String[] split(final String string) {

    // count spaces
    int spaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == 0x20) {
            spaces++;
        }
    }

    // prepare the array and buffer
    final String[] split = new String[spaces + 1];
    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == 0x20) {
            split[index++] = buffer.toString();
            buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
            continue;
        }
        buffer.append(string.charAt(i));
    }

    return split;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are implementations of StringTokenizer in J2me.
check out [this example](http://mobilepit.com/06/solution-stringtokenizer-in-j2me-javame-midlets.html) to help you out with the task.

```
StringTokenizer token;
token = new StringTokenizer(str);
int i=0;
while(token.hasMoreElements()){
ar[i++]= tok.nextToken();
}
```