# read single cell record from csv file in j2me

Tags: csv, java-me

In my J2ME application, I got data from `.csv file` and display all data from file on device. But according to my requirement, I want to display only single cell data on device.So,how can I fetch single cell record from .csv file and display it on device?

"**Update After Comment**"

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + "csvsample.csv");

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

 try {

int chars;

 while ((chars = is.read()) != -1) {

 sb.append((char) chars);

 return sb.toString();

 } catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println("Exception Occurance::" + e);

}

return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: show snippets of code you use to get data from file and to display it on device

Comment: Which problem are you having difficulty with?  Extracting a single datum from a csv, or displaying a string on the screen?  If the answer is "both", I suggest you split your question into two separate questions.

Comment: funkybro:: I get the whole data from csv file, but I just want to display single cell record from csv file. So, please give me solution regarding it.

Comment: "display single cell record" -- this suggests you don't know how to display any text.  But you've accepted an answer that doesn't show how to display any text!  This is a lousy question.

Comment: StackOverflow is for answering SPECIFIC questions, not asking if someone will build a feature for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must read one line at a  time. For this you can use below method:

```
private boolean readLine (InputStream is, StringBuffer line) throws IOException {
    int c = in.read();

    while (c != -1 && c != '\n') {
        line.append((char) c);
        c = in.read();
    }

    return line.length() > 0;
}
```

Then you need to split the line content based on `,` separator, for example, like at this other question [How do I split strings in J2ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200746/how-do-i-split-strings-in-j2me).

```
while (readLine(is, sb)) {
  String line = sb.toString();
  // split line content

  sb.setLength(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to consume the entire InputStream to a string ....

You'd want to use a reader so that you support non-ASCII charsets, and you'd want to read in chunks, not byte-by-byte.

Here's what I use:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

public class StreamUtil {
    public static String consumeInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        char[] buff = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int ret = 0;
        while(ret != -1) {
            ret = reader.read(buff);
            if(ret > 0) {
                sb.append(buff, 0, ret);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

That being said, this question needs a lot of help.  It's hopelessly vague, and you are basically asking for someone to do all the work for you.  If you can clarify it to a very precise and specific question, you'll get much better responses.  StackOverflow is for answering SPECIFIC questions, not asking if someone will build a feature for you.

Comment: all Java ME platforms are currently restricted to JRE 1.3 ([according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_ME)) - this means no `StringBuilder` there because it was introduced in 1.5

Comment: ah, missed that it was J2ME.  s/StringBuilder/StringBuffer/ and my comment still applies.